# Connecting Logstash and Rabbitmq docker containers

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, logstash

I'm trying to launch Logstash from a docker image to send logs to a RabbitMQ instance running on another docker container.

I linked both containers and launched Logstash with the following command and config file:

```
docker run --link rabbitmq:rabbit -it log-sender logstash -f config.conf
```

config.conf:

```
input { 
    stdin {
    } 
}
output {
    rabbitmq {
        host => "RABBIT_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR"
        exchange => "test_exchange"
        exchange_type => "fanout"
    }
}
```

I obtained the following error:

> RabbitMQ connection error: Connection to RABBIT_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR:5672 refused: host unknown. Will attempt to reconnect in 10 seconds... {:exception=>#, :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-
>   2.1.2-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:361:in 'converting_rjc_exceptions_to_ruby'"
>   , "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.1.2-java/lib/march_ha
>   re/session.rb:382:in 'new_connection_impl'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/
>   1.9/gems/march_hare-2.1.2-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:82:in 'initialize'", "/
>   ...
>   uts/rabbitmq/march_hare.rb:18:in 'register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in
>   'each'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:220:in 'outputworker'", "/opt/l
>   ogstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:152:in `start_outputs'"], :level=>:error}

The rabbit docker is the [base image](https://github.com/dockerfile/rabbitmq), run with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq
```

It seems that for some reason my Logstash image can't access to the port of the RabbitMQ image. Using curl I can get the response "AMPQ" when used from the host on port 5672, but not from the Logstash image.

Comment: Is host `RABBIT_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR` reachable? Probably you have to specify conatiner hostname (`-h` or `--hostname`) and use it in your config, or if your logstash also reside inside container then simple `localhost` will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. I got pointed down the right path with the help of [How to reference environment variables in logstash configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999969/how-to-reference-environment-variables-in-logstash-configuration-file).

Remember that your file above is a static Logstash config file. So the string `RABBIT_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR` that appears in the file never gets expanded by Logstash into the actual IP address contained in the environment variable `$RABBIT_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR`.

How do you get the correct IP address into the Logstash config file? **You don't**.

Docker does [some magic](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#updating-the-etc-hosts-file) with /etc/hosts on the containers. If you have your multi-container environment set up correctly, you should see an entry for your Rabbit container's *name* in your *Logstash* container's hosts file.

This allows you to use the *Rabbit container's name* as the address in Logstash config on the Logstash container:

```
rabbitmq {
    host => "name_of_your_rabbit_container"
}
```

If you want to double-check, [copy the Logstash container's hosts file](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/) to your system. Open it up, and you should see an entry with a Docker-generated IP address and the name of your Rabbit container.

Comment: As an aside, consider using [Docker Compose](https://www.docker.com/docker-compose) if you are not doing so already. You still have to set up Logstash config correctly per above, but Docker Compose (via the [yaml file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#links)) will make sure that the containers are configured to talk to each other.