# Environment variable in Logstash not being parsed correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, configuration, environment-variables, logstash

I come here after reading [How to reference environment variables in logstash configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999969/how-to-reference-environment-variables-in-logstash-configuration-file).

Unfortunately it did not work for me. 
I am running:

```
bin/logstash -f my_filters.conf --debug
```

And my config file is:

```
input {
 file {
        path => "/tmp/${RUN_ID}/*.txt"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        ignore_older => 0
    }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
        index => "${RUN_ID}"
    }
}
```

And no new index is being created.
This is **after** setting:

```
export RUN_ID=500
```

For example.
**If I change my config to have a hard-coded value (e.g. 500), then the index is created without a problem.**

I have read the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html) and it mentions exactly what I'm doing right now...
What am I doing wrong, how can I get the environment variable working?

Comment: What version of logstash are you using?  How are you starting logstash after setting the environment variable?

Comment: Logstash 2.5, and I've shown how I'm starting logstash in the question itself.

Comment: According to the ES web site, it doesn't appear that 2.5 is a valid version number... they go from 2.4 to 5.0.  If you are using 1.5, it didn't have that feature, since it was introduced in 2.3.

Comment: I meant 2.4, sorry for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logstash 2.4 requires a command line argument of `--allow-env` to do environment substitutions.

Without the flag it doesn't complain (but doesn't work)

```
bin/logstash -f test.conf 
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
```

With the flag, it will complain if you don't set it:

```
bin/logstash --allow-env -f test.conf  
fetched an invalid config {:config=>"input {\n file {\n        path => \"/tmp/${RUN_ID}/*.txt\"\n        start_position => beginning\n        sincedb_path => \"/dev/null\"\n        ignore_older => 0\n    }\n}\n\noutput {\nstdout { codec=>rubydebug}\n elasticsearch {\n        hosts => [ \"localhost:9200\" ]\n        index => \"${RUN_ID}\"\n    }\n}\n\n\n", :reason=>"Cannot evaluate `${RUN_ID}`. Environment variable `RUN_ID` is not set and there is no default value given.", :level=>:error}
```

And of course with the argument and flag, everything works right:

```
export RUN_ID=10 
bin/logstash --allow-env -f test.conf 
Pipeline main started
{
       "message" => "asdfasdf",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-11-01T21:10:15.964Z",
          "path" => "/tmp/10/test.txt",
          "host" => "XXXXXXXXX.local"
}
```

Comment: Thank you **so** much! I can't believe they didn't explicitely mention this in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html)!